# Pre-Flight OPTIONS requests are canceled in Chrome (CORS already supported)

Tags: django, angular, google-chrome, http, cors

I'm working on a project that use Angular + Django(Django Rest Framework). During the development, the CORS support is done by using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers), with `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`.

When I'm trying to send POST requests to create some resources in frontend (Angular), some pre-flight OPTIONS requests are sent by Chrome and responded successfully by backend server (python manage.py runserver), but others are not. These requests are canceled due to unknown reason, backend server logs indicate that requests are received and accepted by server, details are shown in fig below.

[image: Some OPTIONS requests are failed]

[image: Backend server logs]

The headers of failed requests are shown below.

[image: Details of failed request]

However, if a copy the content of the headers and try sending it with `curl`, it works as expected.

```
$ curl -v -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "DNS: 1" -H "Origin: http://localhost:4200" -H "Referer: http://localhost:4200" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" http:/localhost:8000/api/user-permissions/
* Unwillingly accepted illegal URL using 1 slash!
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /api/user-permissions/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> DNS: 1
> Origin: http://localhost:4200
> Referer: http://localhost:4200
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 02:47:39 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.1
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 0
< Vary: Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Any ideas how this happen? Thx.

---

Sample Code:

```
// The method of the component that invokes the methods of PermissionService.
  /** Update selected user's permissions. */
  updatePermissions() {
    const diff = this.diffPermissions();
    const toBeCreated = diff[0];
    const toBeDeleted = diff[1];
    this.isLoading = true;
    zip(
      this.permissionService.createUserPermissions(toBeCreated),
      this.permissionService.deleteUserPermissions(toBeDeleted),
    ).pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(err.message);
        return observableOf(false);
      }),
    ).subscribe(succeed => {
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

// The methods of PermissionService that issue the HTTP requests.

  createUserPermission(req: UserPermissionRequest) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.API_URL}/user-permissions/`, req);
  }

  createUserPermissions(reqs: UserPermissionRequest[]) {
    // TODO(youchen): Evaluate the performance cost.
    return forkJoin(reqs.map(req => this.createUserPermission(req)));
  }

  deleteUserPermission(permissionId: number) {
    return this.http.delete(`${environment.API_URL}/user-permissions/${permissionId}/`);
  }

  deleteUserPermissions(permissionIds: number[]) {
    // TODO(youchen): Evaluate the performance cost.
    return forkJoin(permissionIds.map(id => this.deleteUserPermission(id)));
  }
```

Comment: The *“Provisional headers are shown”* in the Request Headers section usually indicates the browser is loading the response from its cache rather than sending a new request over the network. What error message is logged in the devtools console when that happens? And can you reproduce the failure in Firefox or any other browser?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I completed these actions under incognito mode both in Chrome and Safari. No messages are shown in devtools console (when OPTIONS requests are canceled). But if I `Disable Cross-Origin restrictions` in Safari(incognito mode), then no OPTIONS requests are sent, but I get error in Django log, `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`. I'm curious about why some OPTIONS requests are succeed while others aren't.

Comment: Do those OPTIONS requests show up in Safari as canceled too? If the devtools console shows no errors, then exactly in what way is the request failing? How did you determine it’s failed? If there’s any CORS issue, or a network error, browsers will log some message in the devtool console. So if nothing’s logged in the console, that’d seem to indicate the browser has determined it’s just doing what your frontend code asked it to do. So maybe something in your frontend code is causing those requests to be canceled. But you haven’t shown your code, so nobody else here can do more than just guess

Comment: @sideshowbarker Yes, they are. Ideally, the real POST request should be sent after OPTIONS request completed, but in my case, the OPTIONS request was canceled and no POST request was sent after that. The sample code have been added above, the entrance of these logic is `updatePermissions()`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause: **`zip()` with no parameters**

In my case, I'm using `zip` to combine creations and deletions, see:

```
const createRequests = [c1, c2];
const deleteRequests = [d1, d2];

zip(
  this.service.create(createRequests),
  this.service.delete(deleteRequests),
)....

---
service.ts

create(reqs: CreateRequest[]) {
  return zip(...reqs.map(req => this.createSingle(req));
}

delete(reqs: DeleteRequest[]) {
  return zip(...reqs.map(req => this.deleteSingle(req));
}
```

But if one of the `createRequests` and `deleteRequests` is an empty list, this logic will go wrong. For example, if `createRequests` is empty while `deleteRequests` isn't, all HTTP requests fired by `this.service.delete(deleteRequests)` will be canceled due to an empty `zip()` is returned by `this.service.create(createRequests)`.

Solution:

The solution to this problem is that we check the length of the `reqs` and return other observable instaned.

Fixed code:

```
create(reqs: CreateRequest[]) {
  if (reqs.length === 0) return of([]);
  return zip(...reqs.map(req => this.createSingle(req));
}

delete(reqs: DeleteRequest[]) {
  if (reqs.length === 0) return of([]);
  return zip(...reqs.map(req => this.deleteSingle(req));
}
```